# Why doesn't post method do anything?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a server that uses simple routing without using a framework and saves received data to a file. In order to do that I ought to be able to get my submit-button to do something, but now it seems it doesn't.

```
 const http = require('http');
 var url = require('url');
 const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
 const port = 3000;

 const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 if(req.url == "/save"){
    if(req.method === 'POST'){
        console.log("Why, why, nothing happens?.");
        res.end("What is wrong?");
    }
    else{
        res.end(`
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <body>
                <form action="/" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="data" /><br />
                    <button>Save</button>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
        `);
    }
  }
 });

 server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: in  `form` change the action url from '/' to '/save' or else, if you dont want  to change in form , you also can change `if(req.url == "/save"){` to `if(req.url == "/"){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the URL you are POSTing to:

> ```
> action="/"
> ```

---

This is a simplified version of your code:

```
if(req.url == "/save"){
    // Do something
}
```

---

It does nothing because it doesn't pass your `if` condition (`"/" !== "/save"`!) and you don't have an `else` branch.

Comment: It seems to pass the condition when I type "http://localhost:3000/save" in Chrome's address bar after typing "node app.js" to vagrant.

Comment: @mrSimple — Unsurprisingly `"/save" === "/save"`, it is `"/"` that doesn't.

Comment: How should I change it? Does it change from "/save" to "/" when clicking Save-button?

Comment: @mrSimple — Look at the very first thing I said in my answer.

Comment: Yup. Solved. Thanks.